# brew install Error: Command failed with exit 129: git

Tags: git, homebrew

Whenever I try to run brew to install a package I receive this error:

```
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
Error: Command failed with exit 129: git
```

Im trying to install by using this command:

`brew install golang-migrate`

P.S: I already removed and install homebrew

Comment: `git --version` ?

Comment: git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)

Comment: Option `-C` must be in the help: see https://git-scm.com/docs/git . I suspect `brew` somehow installed and used VERY old `git`.

Comment: I noticed that it must be lowercase, but idk what to do :(

Comment: No, `-C path` and `-c name=value` are completely different options. Compare [`-C path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt) and [`-c name=value`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt).

Comment: I just checked — Git 1.8 doesn't have option `-C`. Somehow `brew` installed and used VERY old `git`. First try to upgrade its Git.

Comment: @phd: curious... brew should definitely not be installing an ancient 1.8 Git version, I wonder how that would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, as homebrew puts the binaries at `/opt/homebrew/bin`

Adding this to the `~/.bash_profile` will precedence homebrew `git` over apple's `git`

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```